# How to filter by all in queryset

Tags: django

I've got a queryset within a function. In some cases, I want to filter by a specific model.

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(model='Toyota')
```

In other cases, I don't want to filter by this field at all. Eg. (Syntax is wrong, but it demonstrates what I'm after)

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(model=all)
```

How do I include a field within a queryset as shown above, but prevent it from limiting the results?

Thanks!

Comment: `Car.objects.all()`?

Comment: Could you override all before passing to `filter()`?

Comment: Why is `.all()` not enough for you? What else do you have to filter it against?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom manager for your model and modify `filter()`.

```
from django.db import models


class NewManager(models.Manager):
    def filter(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs == {'model': 'all'}
            return self.all()
        else:
            return self.filter(**kwargs)
```

And define the new manager in the model.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/) is more details about manager.